# jQuery hide items in an array to another

Tags: jquery, arrays, compare

I want to compare two list to eliminate items that do not repeated.

List 1 :

```
<ul class="tab_link">
<li><a href="#product_tabs_related_products" onclick="javascript:csTablist.remoteTabs('product_tabs_related_products');">Complétez votre achat</a></li>
<li><a href="#product_tabs_description" onclick="javascript:csTablist.remoteTabs('product_tabs_description');">Description du produit</a></li>
<li><a href="#product_tabs_product_additional_data" onclick="javascript:csTablist.remoteTabs('product_tabs_product_additional_data');">Avis client</a></li>
<li><a href="#product_tabs_web4pro_attachments" onclick="javascript:csTablist.remoteTabs('product_tabs_web4pro_attachments');">Pièces jointes</a> </li>
</ul>
```

List 2 :

```
<ul class="product-tabs">
<li id="product_tabs_description" class=""><a href="javascript:void(0)">Description du produit</a></li>
<li id="product_tabs_product_additional_data" class=""><a href="javascript:void(0)">Avis client</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have to hide the list of items that are one too many.

I can combine two array.

```
var list1 = [];

// Identify the list1 values.
$x('.product-tabs').find('a').each(function(index,value) {
list1.push($x(this).text());
});

var list2 = [];

// Identify the list2 values.
$x('.tab_link').find('a').each(function(index,value) {
list2.push($x(this).text());
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide items from list1 that are not in list2, you can try doing something like that : Listing the elements from list2 and loop through list1 hiding elements you don't find in list 2 :

```
var list1 = [];

// Identify the list1 values.
$('.product-tabs').find('a').each(function() {
  list1.push($(this).text());
});



// Identify the list2 values.
$('.tab_link').find('a').each(function() {
  if(-1 == $.inArray($(this).text(), list1)) {$(this).parent().hide();}
});
```

[See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k90ah3ao/)

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution based on the filter jQuery function is:

```js
function getUniqElems() {
  return $('ul.tab_link li a').filter(function(index, element) {
    if ($('#' + $(element).attr('href').substr(1)).length != 1) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });

}

function printResults(obj) {
  $.each(obj, function(index, element) {
    $('#result').append($(element).clone());
    $('#result').append('<br />');
  });
}

$(function () {
  $('#doAndPrint').on('click', function() {
    var resutArray = getUniqElems();
    printResults(resutArray);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<ul class="tab_link">
    <li><a href="#product_tabs_related_products" onclick="javascript:csTablist.remoteTabs('product_tabs_related_products');">Complétez votre achat</a></li>
    <li><a href="#product_tabs_description" onclick="javascript:csTablist.remoteTabs('product_tabs_description');">Description du produit</a></li>
    <li><a href="#product_tabs_product_additional_data" onclick="javascript:csTablist.remoteTabs('product_tabs_product_additional_data');">Avis client</a></li>
    <li><a href="#product_tabs_web4pro_attachments" onclick="javascript:csTablist.remoteTabs('product_tabs_web4pro_attachments');">Pièces jointes</a> </li>
</ul>

<ul class="product-tabs">
    <li id="product_tabs_description" class=""><a href="javascript:void(0)">Description du produit</a></li>
    <li id="product_tabs_product_additional_data" class=""><a href="javascript:void(0)">Avis client</a></li>
</ul>

<button id="doAndPrint">Click me</button>

<p id="result">Results:<br /></p>
```